# multipath routing

Tags: routing, tcp

I have a client-server network in which the client has two interfaces on two different network. Say that ethO has ip address 10.0.0.10 and eth1 20.0.0.10
The client has two gateways 10.0.0.1 and 20.0.0.1 respectively (two routing tables). eth0 and eth1 is connected to the router through link 0 and link 1 resp. 
The server has ip address 30.0.0.10
I want the router to be able to route packets to eth1 through link 0 (for e.g when link 1 is broken). Is it possible to do dynamically ?

client   (link 0)      Router           Server
|eth0  |---------|++|---------| |
|eth1  |---------|++|
                  (link 1)

(note : I'm using MPTCP both on client & server)

Comment: This question seems more directed at Linux configuration and as such makes it off-topic here. As Ogi has mentioned below can use the `brctl` tools to create a bridge and use the two links two transport the same VLAN or you can keep them as they are both as layer 3 and set different metrics for each link in the Linux routing table. It's best you ask on another StackExhange site like ServerFault or Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the router ip address on interface vlan or some logical interface that have the ability to 'reach' the two interfaces toward client.
2. Set br0 interface and add eth0 and eth1 to this interface on client side.
3. Ensure STP is allowed on the vlan used for this router-client connectivity.

This way if eth0 going down eth1 will become the active port. Else eth0 is active and eth1 is in STP blocking state.

Comment: Can you develop more ? how do i make the logical interface reach the two interfaces toward client ?

Comment: if the vendor is cisco - interface vlan.

Comment: All my machines are linux

Comment: then bridge with stp